# Custom icon set for Windows File explorer placeholder/offline files (boxDrive)

Tags: c++, winapi, icons, cloud

Need help in programmatically setting custom icons for the files(Placeholder files) which are synced from the cloud providers in Windows file explorer.

BoxDrive provides effective file sync up using the Windows concept of placeholder/offline files in Windows file explorer. Placeholder files are web reference/link files with minimum metadata, and these files get downloaded/hydrated when users interact with such placeholder files.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-create-icon-handlers article explains how to implement custom icon for different files in Windows File Explorer. Based on that we have implemented the interface [IPersistFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-ipersistfile) and [IExtractIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nn-shlobj_core-iextracticona).

The problem we are facing is for placeholder files we are not getting callback of IPersistFile::Load and IExtractIcon::GetIconLocation where we can customize the icon for the file based on our logic.

If user hovers or click the placeholder files then such callback comes and then we can show icon, But the issue is for the files which were just synced from the cloud as placeholder files in the Windows explorer.

Please help what can be done to change the Icon of placeholder/Dehydrated files in windows explorer using the c++ win32 interface.

Comment: AFAIK, only OneDrive uses "real" Windows placeholders, others are using regular files. Are you talking specifically about OneDrive? PS: don't use IExtractIconA use IExtractIconW

Comment: @SimonMourier More specificly I was talking about BoxDrive but IINW such cloud storage provider uses placeholder or dehydrated files which only have metadata and downloads the content on user actions.
Yes I am using IExtractIcon which resolve to IExtractIconW.

Comment: BoxDrive uses another technology, it's a junction/mount point with "offline" files, it's not what OneDrive uses.

Comment: @SimonMourier thx, But still the question of why callbacks for such offline files not coming for icon change GetIconLocation and Load? 
Any hint or Microsoft document which you know for Box's use of junction/mount point with "offline" files ?

Comment: When you look at the Box drive in Explorer of common dialogs, you're looking at a Shell namespace extension (over the mount point), not the regular Shell view (there's a hidden+system desktop.ini file at the root) of the box drive. A Shell namespace extension has complete control of icon & thumbnails and BTW, you can remark it doesn't display the same icons as other Shell views.